# The codeScanner doesn't work when it's used with my application

Tags: codenameone

I have a problem with the code scanner, I use this lib https://github.com/codenameone/cn1-codescan in my application to scan the barcode. I work on an android application and I try to scan code_128 code format.

```
public class ScanQr extends Form {
final Container cnt = this;
public ScanQr(Form parent){
    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
    final RadioButton qr = new RadioButton("QR Code");
    final RadioButton bar = new RadioButton("Bar Code");
    bg.add(qr);
    bg.add(bar);
    this.addComponent(new Label("Code Type"));
    this.addComponent(qr);
    this.addComponent(bar);

    Button scanBtn = new Button("Scan Code");
    scanBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            if(qr.isSelected()){
                CodeScanner.getInstance().scanQRCode(new ScanResult() {
                    public void scanCompleted(String contents, String formatName, byte[] rawBytes) {
                        //barCode.setText("Bar: " + contents);
                        cnt.addComponent(new Label(contents));
                        cnt.revalidate();
                    }

                    public void scanCanceled() {
                        cnt.addComponent(new Label("cancelled"));
                    }

                    public void scanError(int errorCode, String message) {
                        cnt.addComponent(new Label("err " + message));
                    }
                });
            }else{
                CodeScanner.getInstance().scanBarCode(new ScanResult() {
                    public void scanCompleted(String contents, String formatName, byte[] rawBytes) {
                        //barCode.setText("Bar: " + contents);
                        cnt.addComponent(new Label(contents));
                        cnt.revalidate();
                    }

                    public void scanCanceled() {
                        cnt.addComponent(new Label("cancelled"));
                    }

                    public void scanError(int errorCode, String message) {
                        cnt.addComponent(new Label("err " + message));
                    }
                });        
            }
        }

    });
    if (CodeScanner.isSupported()) {
        this.addComponent(scanBtn);
    } else {
        this.addComponent(new SpanLabel("Sorry.  Codescanner not supported on this platform"));
    }
}
```

}

First it installs Barcode Scanner+ Simple if it's not installed then when this app is used with my application, it takes a lot of time to find and display the information scanned on the barcode or it doesn't find anything but when I just use Barcode Scanner+ Simple alone, it works very well, I don't have any problem with it.

I don't understand where's the problem since I use the same codescanner application but in 2 differents contexts, when it's launched alone and when it's launched with my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to try narrowing the types that are scanned to get a better result e.g. do this some time before invoking the scan:

```
Display.getInstance().setProperty("android.scanTypes", "CODE_128");
```